# Why does Levi wear Titan Pajamas?

Tags: attack-on-titan

[image: Levi's Pajamas]

Does this have anything to do with the manga? Or is this just something that fans made up? Because I see so much people cosplaying as Levi in Titan Pajamas.

Comment: Having read all the chapters so far, as far as I can tell, there's been no mention of Levi's pajamas at all. I'd have thought it's just a fan-based thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is fanmade.

The origin of the image is from [阿布 (Abu)'s Pixiv](http://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=medium&illust_id=35832680). He also drew some more [Levi with Titan Pajamas](http://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=manga&illust_id=38073882), and [other characters with Pajamas](http://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=manga&illust_id=38915838).

Seems it became popular after the image was shared on Baidu, with the real pajamas being sold.

Reference: [AnimeAmino - Levi's pajamas](http://aminoapps.com/page/anime/4107556/levis-pajamas)